# NSURLRequest setHTTPBody readonly

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

```
NSURLRequest *r = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[r setHTTPBody:imageData];
r.HTTPBody = imageData;
```

Xcode gives an error on the second line: `"No visible interface for 'NSURLRequest declares the selector 'setHTTPBody'"`

and the third line `"Assignment to readonly property"`

but the class definition shows

```
/*! 
    @method HTTPBody:
    @abstract Sets the request body data of the receiver.
    @discussion This data is sent as the message body of the request, as
    in done in an HTTP POST request.
    @param data the new request body data for the receiver.
*/
@property (copy) NSData *HTTPBody;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular `NSURLRequest` is immutable. Use `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

You provided definition from `NSMutableURLRequest` but use `NSURLRequest` where this property is read only.